How do you redirect your local machine to go to www.google.com when www.microsoft.com is entered in the browser's URL bar?
If I modify my /etc/hosts file from this:
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost

to this:
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
127.0.0.1       www.microsoft.com

This will redirect any attempt to access www.microsoft.com to 127.0.0.1, effectively blocking access to www.microsoft.com.  This works great.
Now, instead of redirecting to localhost, I want to redirect to another website, for example, I want to change my /etc/hosts to look like:
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
www.google.com       www.microsoft.com

However, when I try to visit www.microsoft.com, it never redirects me to www.google.com. It just goes straight to www.microsoft.com and ignores what I did in /etc/hosts.
Does anyone know how to fix this or how this can be achieved?

Check this

In addition to Marcus' correct explanation that the browser may be bypassing the hosts file:
The hosts file can ONLY resolve a name to an address, not to another name. Something like
142.250.31.99 www.microsoft.com

or
2607:f8b0:4004:c1b::63 www.microsoft.com

will, once your browser is using the hosts file, cause your request to connect to google, at least until the next time google feels like altering their IP routing, then you'll have to manually update it.
But it won't work for web requests. After resolving and connecting to the address, HTTP sends the hostname in the request header. So your browser will connect to google, and send a request saying "I want the landing page for www.microsoft.com". Google will say "WTF? I'm not www.microsoft.com" and give an error.
And if you make an HTTPS request, either explicitly or because the website has previously sent you an HSTS header (although www.microsoft.com doesn't, at least for me) and/or preloaded HSTS, the browser will first do a TLS handshake with SNI asking for www.microsoft.com; many hosts will reject such a wrong-host connection at the TLS level, but google (currently?) doesn't and, like a normal TLS connection, provides its certificate -- which of course is a certificate for google not microsoft, so the browser rejects it with an error something like "I can't reach www.microsoft.com because your connection has been intercepted by unauthorized or evil malfeasors".
(AFAIK no browser actually says "malfeasors", but I like the sound of it.)

aaaah right, yeah, was having a bad brain evening there!

The usual recipes for redirecting, based on /etc/hosts or local DNS setups, will usually not work for a modern browsers; these, very often to by default, use DNS over TLS or DNS over HTTPS with custom servers to be independent from local name resolution. Which on one hand sends all the name lookups you do to a central server, so it feels a bit questionable privacy-wise, on the other hand, it stops your ISP from interfering with these – and that's quite a common occurrence, especially on wifi hotspots, where a redirect on the first HTTPS request can lead to quite confusing failures rather than the portal page of the website being shown.
So, you'd have to configure your Name Resolution in your browser to not use DNS over HTTPS. (search for "DNS" in firefox' settings dialog) for this to work in general.
That aside, what you do should work, if you follow Dave Thompson's answer. Note that browsers have their own resolvers with their own resolver caches; I don't know whether they immediately refresh their resolution if it's still valid and you change a /etc/hosts entry.
Frankly, if you want to block certain domains, and their subdomains, it's probably worth going for a browser plugin which allows you to do that. Chrome just disabled the option to do that in a plugin, so your browser of choice becomes firefox, with the uBlock origin plugin.

That's true but only the first problem.
